Issue with the tikz code to plot Brownian Motion
I am trying to adapt the codes from this post to plot Brownian Motions via tikz --
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{invgauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(-2*ln(#1))*cos(deg(2*pi*#2))}%
}

\newcommand{\Brownian}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(#2,invgauss(0.1,0.3))
}
node[right] {#5};
}

However, I am getting this latex error:
Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the logarithm o
f `0' (in 'sqrt(-2*ln(0))*cos(deg(2*pi*.))'). 

Could you please help? Thanks for your time. If I follow the suggestion by @Qrrbrbirlbel to put invgauss within {} and then use the rand/2+0.5 to generate uniform random variables within [0,1]: -- ++(#2,{invgauss({rand/2+0.5},{rand/2+0.5})}), it starts working.
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{invgauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(-2*ln(#1))*cos(deg(2*pi*#2))}%
}
\newcommand{\Brownian}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(#2,{invgauss({rand/2+0.5},{rand/2+0.5})})
}
node[right] {#5};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Brownian{750}{0.02}{0.001}{red}{first one}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Welcome. Firstly, write ++(#2,{invgauss(0.1,0.3)}). Secondly, please post a MWE.

Awesome, thanks a lot. This change was enough to solve the issue. I will edit post to reflect this.
